# How do you create pages programmatically with drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I currently have a Drupal website. I need to make 1000 pages that are in the form domain.com/names/name1.html domain.com/names/name2.html etc. Each differs slightly but is in the same format. What is the best way to go around this? I am having trouble finding any tutorials on this topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drupal create node with body programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43798350/drupal-create-node-with-body-programmatically)

Comment: Also, searching google for "drupal 7 create node" yields many results

Comment: Also, there is a specific site for drupal answers. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @2pha The op asks for how to create drupal PAGES programmatically, why would you want him to google that ?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? What content should be loaded on these pages ?

Comment: @EricLavault Because I am assuming he means the node type "basic page" that is in the default drupal install. What do you think the OP means when he says "Pages" ?
If it isn't nodes that he wants, then the question is way to vague and there are too many possible ways to give any constructive advice here.

Comment: [Assumptions](https://medium.com/thrive-global/9-reasons-why-making-assumptions-is-dangerous-345e8b24008c).. I think the OP means 'pages' when he refers to 'pages'. I won't assume he means 'node' instead, because there is no reason to think of a confusion between drupal-node vs drupal-page concepts, and because that would mean he did not catch the fact that published nodes can be already accessed at path following the pattern `node/<nid>`. I asked for precision instead of assuming and throwing a google advice, that is most of the time more disrespectful than helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first clarify.

As the comments under your question suggested you could **1. create nodes programmatically**. Let's say you have a content type (a node type) "Page" and then by calling `hook_install` (to perform the task upon module installation) or `hook_update_N` (to perform the task upon running the update routine) from within a custom module you could create a thousand nodes of type "Page" (in a for-loop or better as a batch process to prevent timeouts), set their path alias and whatever else you need to set, done. There are a tons of tutorials out there already.

And of course you also can **2. create pages programmatically** by calling `hook_menu` from within a custom module and adding a menu item (a route) which accepts wildcards (`$items['names/%']`). You then can define a callback function (`'page callback'`) to build your page content that will be called when a matching URL gets accessed and you can also pass the wildcards as arguments (`'page arguments'`) to that callback function. The callback function could simply return a render array for example.

Adding a menu item with a callback function to render some custom content via `hook_menu` normally means you really only control the inner page content dynamically (the main page content region or however it's called in your current theme). Header, main menu, footer etc. simply stay the same. Depending on your needs you also need to build custom links to your custom pages somehow and provide them as custom block or whatever you are planning to do with them.

A good overview of the second approach can be found in the Example module's docs and in detail in the **Page Example** submodule's docs.

- `hook_menu` example: [page_example_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/page_example%21page_example.module/function/page_example_menu/7.x-1.x)
- the example page callback function: [page_example_description](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/page_example%21page_example.module/function/page_example_description/7.x-1.x)
- all [Example Page](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/page_example%21page_example.module/group/page_example/7.x-1.x) functions